# React.js can't display API data in the UI with useEffect & fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I am trying to display the data from an API in the UI. I can see the data in the console but I always get an error when I'm trying to map through the data in the return. Ideally I would like to access all the objects that is in the results array.

Here is the code of the `App.js` and a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-cookies-i8zkm?file=/src/App.js) if you want to test it.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    results: []
  });
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const api = "https://apis.is/earthquake/is";
  useEffect(() => {
    //if (!api) return;
    setLoading(true);
    fetch(api)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(setData)
      .then(() => setLoading(false))
      .catch(setError);
  }, []);

  if (loading) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  if (error) return <pre>{JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)}</pre>;
  if (!data) return null;
  //{JSON.stringify(data)}
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data.results[1]);
  if (data.results) {
    return (
      <div>
        {data.results.map((i) => (
          <li key={i.results}> {i.humanReadableLocation}</li>
        ))}{" "}
      </div>
    );
  }
  return <div> Failed to get data </div>;
}
```

Comment: UPDATE: I am writing this code in a different component and I forgot to import it to App.js ‍♀️ and the export default function was indeed missing as well. thanks Prakash S for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `export default` is missing

```js
import "./styles.css";

import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    results: []
  });
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const api = "https://apis.is/earthquake/is";
  useEffect(() => {
    //if (!api) return;
    setLoading(true);
    fetch(api)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(setData)
      .then(() => setLoading(false))
      .catch(setError);
  }, []);

  if (loading) return <h1 > Loading... < /h1>;
  if (error) return <pre > {
    JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)
  } < /pre>;
  if (!data) return null;
  //{JSON.stringify(data)}
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data.results[1]);
  if (data.results) {
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      p > virka plíssss < /p>  {data.results.map((i) => (
      <li key={i.results}> {i.humanReadableLocation}</li>
    ))} <
      /div>
    );
  }
  return <div > Oops, náðist ekki að sækja gögn < /div>;
}
```

[Updated code sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-boyd-fp1tl?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

What are you even trying to output? The results is an object. Here is a sample, but you need to decide what property you want in the LI, the key should probably not be an Object, pick a property.

```
{data.results.map((i) => (
      <li key={i.results}> {i.timestamp}</li>
    ))}
```